# firebase.json serving webp, unsetting headers and internal redirects

Tags: firebase-hosting

I'm used to a little more control of the server config. Now in firebase.json I am looking for

- internal redirects
- accept header rules (so I can vary response, eg. webp instead of jpg)
- regular expressions (globbing can't easily match index files / folders)
- unsetting headers (eg. CSP header override for resources)

Am I mis-reading the "full configuration" example or are these missing currently.